# Mongodb query from any array position

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My schema looks like this:

```
{
  _id: "myid"
  user: [{"name":"Bob"}, {"name":"Jenny"}]
},
{
  _id: "myid2"
  user: [{"name":"John"}, {"name":"Jenny"}]
},
{
  _id: "myid3"
  user: [{"name":"John"}, {"name":"Bob"}]
}
```

I want to find all the documents Bob is an user of. He could be any any position in the array. Could this be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) db.test.find({'user.name': 'Bob'})

2) db.test.find({'user' : { $elemMatch : {'name' :  'Bob'}}})